# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException for specific URL

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

I am getting this error when calling API, but this error is not coming to the app the API URLs.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme
>   specific part at index 6: https:

Comment: Please provide additional information as well as the part of code in which the error occures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem with come if `URL` having space ,so please check your `API` `URL` is it having space , and try like this

```
String URL=URLEncoder.encode(path,."UTF-8");
```

And finally use the above `URL` for `API` call.